# Taxonomy parent terms - pathauto

Tags: taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

Pattern for taxonomy terms is `[term:parent]/[term:name]` where car is parent and BMW is child

Path is looking like this when I am on child term page:
**www.mysite.com/car/bmw**

In menu I have link to /car and when I am there it displays a list of all child terms. Thats fine.

But when I generate XML sitemap I see /car/bmw (all good), but for strange reason there is link taxonomy/term/1 and which leads to page without any content or terms in it, while it should redirect to /car.

There is no /car link found.

To avoid duplicate content I am not sure how to avoid this. I tried recreating all paths bit no luck

*Edit:*

To elaborate in more details.
Vocabulary has several parents, each 100 childs.
Childs are displaying correctly as i have described above. 
For each parent i created separate view to display several fields. 
Filter is set to Taxonomy Term: Parent term. Is equal to "value", where value is taxonomy tid. Lets say that for this view value is 1 (term car)
I also have relationship with Identifier: Parent. Require this relationship is on.

Path is set to /car
Menu to Normal menu item "CAR".

When i go on homepage and click on menu item CAR everything is fine.

In meantime i deleted and bulk updated all taxonomy and now instead of getting old /taxonomy/term/1 or "/car" path for tid 1, i got "car-0".

View that is in menu "CAR" is still displaying ok, path is ok ("car"), but sitemap cant find this url but instead finds "car-0".
Going to path "car-0" displaying nothing, not the terms nor the content it is tagged with.

Answer (score 0):

After testing out for a day various combinations it was a problem with a view page that had path same as taxonomy/term/1.

So I renamed the view page path to car/bmw12, deleted taxonomy aliases and recreated them.

It was easy thing to do. I did not think of it earlier as i was lead by assumption that when you use pathauto to recreate paths it would do it for terms no matter if the path was taken in views already.